# I want to implement javamelody in livyServer, Please let me how can i do this

Tags: apache-spark, livy, java-melody

Hi I need to implement the javamelody so that i can know how much time is consuming by which call. SO please help me to implement this.

Comment: I already did it .

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in LivyServer.scala and javamelody and jrobin dependency in pom.xml

import net.bull.javamelody._

// JavaMelody Filter
val melodyHolder = new FilterHolder(new MonitoringFilter())
melodyHolder.setInitParameter(Parameter.AUTHORIZED_USERS.getCode(), "username:password")
melodyHolder.setInitParameter(Parameter.STORAGE_DIRECTORY.getCode(), "/tmp/javamelody")
server.context.addFilter(melodyHolder, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(classOf[DispatcherType]))

Comment: You should also add the javamelody SessionListener in the server context.